# Cannot understand the output of seqefsub funct

Tags: r, traminer

A simple example:

`t<-data.frame(id=rep(1:3, each=3), time=c(0,2,4,0,4,2,0,2,2), event=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), 3))
tmp<-seqecreate(t)
seqefsub(tmp, min.support=2)`

I'm getting:

```
      Subsequence Support Count
      1         (A)       1     3
      2     (A)-(B)       1     3
      3     (A)-(C)       1     3
      4         (B)       1     3
      5         (C)       1     3
```

I can't understand why (A)-(B) and (A)-(C) counts are 3. 
I have three sequences:

```
    (A)-2-(B)-2-(C) 
    (A)-2-(C)-2-(B) 
    (A)-2-(B,C)
```

It should be:

```
      Subsequence Support Count
      1         (A)       1     3
      2         (B)       1     3
      3         (C)       1     3
      4     (A)-(B)       0.66  2
      5     (A)-(C)       0.66  2
```

A lot of thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're seeing the count of `(A) - (B)` as 3 is because `seqefsub` reads sequences as `(A) - <anything can go here> - (B)` as an instance of `(A) - (B)`, and you have three such instances.

If you want to see the subsequences where `(A) - (B)` occur consecutively and only consecutively, try:

```
>seqefsub(tmp, min.support=2, constraint = seqeconstraint(window.size = 2))
  Subsequence   Support Count
1         (A) 1.0000000     3
2         (B) 1.0000000     3
3         (C) 1.0000000     3
4     (A)-(B) 0.6666667     2
5     (A)-(C) 0.6666667     2

Computed on 3 event sequences
   Constraint Value
  window.size     2
 count.method  COBJ
```